# Binding a control to a behavior property tries to set the property to a Binding instead of the control

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have the following set of numeric entries with behaviours that should shift focus between them as digits are entered or removed:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Label>Enter Code</Label>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" x:Name="FirstDigit" Text="{Binding Digit1}">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <behaviours:DigitEntryBehaviour NextDigit="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=SecondDigit}}" />
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" x:Name="SecondDigit" Text="{Binding Digit2}">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <behaviours:DigitEntryBehaviour PrevDigit="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=FirstDigit}}" NextDigit="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=ThirdDigit}}" />
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" x:Name="ThirdDigit" Text="{Binding Digit3}">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <behaviours:DigitEntryBehaviour PrevDigit="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=SecondDigit}}" NextDigit="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=FourthDigit}}" />
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" x:Name="FourthDigit" Text="{Binding Digit4}">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <behaviours:DigitEntryBehaviour PrevDigit="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=ThirdDigit}}" />
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
    </StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Open"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Below is DigitEntryBehaviour

```
public class DigitEntryBehaviour : Behavior<Entry>
{
    public Entry PrevDigit { get; set; }
    public Entry NextDigit { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        bindable.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var entry = (Entry)sender;

        if (entry.Text.Length > 1)
        {
            entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
            entry.Text = e.OldTextValue;
            entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
            string newChar = e.NewTextValue.Substring(1);
            if (NextDigit != null)
                NextDigit.Text = newChar;
        }
        else if (entry.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            NextDigit?.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            PrevDigit?.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, I get the following exception:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 18:53. Cannot assign
>   property "NextDigit": Property does not exists, or is not assignable,
>   or mismatching type between value and property'

I tried setting the type of the NextDigit and PrevDigit properties of DigitEntryBehaviour to object to see what type it was trying to assign to them, and it seems that it's trying to set them to `Binding`s instead of `Entry`s. Why is it doing this? How do I get it to correctly bind the `Entry`s to these properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `Binding` to work - the target property has to be a bindable property, while the target object should be a `BindableObject`.

As `DigitEntryBehaviour` is not a `BindableObject` - you can't declare bindable properties - and hence not create binding(s).

Simplest option to resolve this would be to remove the `Binding` markup extension and directly use the `Reference` extension to provide the `Entry` control reference(s). i.e. `NextDigit="{x:Reference Name=SecondDigit}"`.

**Updated XAML**

```
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" x:Name="FirstDigit" Text="{Binding Digit1}">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:DigitEntryBehaviour NextDigit="{x:Reference Name=SecondDigit}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" x:Name="SecondDigit" Text="{Binding Digit2}">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:DigitEntryBehaviour PrevDigit="{x:Reference Name=FirstDigit}" NextDigit="{x:Reference Name=ThirdDigit}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" x:Name="ThirdDigit" Text="{Binding Digit3}">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:DigitEntryBehaviour PrevDigit="{x:Reference Name=SecondDigit}" NextDigit="{x:Reference Name=FourthDigit}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" x:Name="FourthDigit" Text="{Binding Digit4}">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:DigitEntryBehaviour PrevDigit="{x:Reference Name=ThirdDigit}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```